# Trying to use two 3 way switches and a 4 way switch to operate 2 - 54187 Bennett Collections using one remote

Tags: basement, ceiling-fan

Can I make the two fan/lights work by switching them at 3 different places [2 3ways and 1- 4 way switch]  and also use the remote to operate both fan/lights? .... 
 ..... Or will I have to wire two more 3 ways and one more 4 way to operate the lights separate from the fans? .... 
YIPES! HELP!

Comment: Are you open to using a different remote + receiver than the one that came with the fan?

Comment: Also, can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved?

Comment: I'd be willing to use another type remote and I'd be willing to take photo., but it will be Monday before I can return to the house .... sure do appreciate all the responses ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a matter of electrical circuitry. You can connect up any piece of control for equipment using your 3 3ways and 1 4way, and if done properly will switch the equipment on and off.

So right now when your circuit is in the off position there is no electricity available at your fans. When the circuitry is on the on position, there is electricity at the fans. Your controller for your remote is inline with this circuitry. So you can switch each light and fan off and on with the remote only if the circuit is in the on position.

In control speak we say, all stops are wired in series and all starts are wired in parallel. Using mechanical switches in series with the electronic controllers means your normal status is stop or off. Trying to wire in parallel with the equipment you specified means the normal status is start or on and the circuit would never turn off.

You might be able to use electronic (smart) switches and the remotes together but they would have to be addressed properly to coordinate with the controllers.

Hope this helps shed some light, so to speak.

Comment: The electronic smart switches might be the answer. The home owner feels that it should be a simple fix. Your answer to power on fan and light works and power off nothing works makes the home p

Comment: Could you expand on the smart switches that could / would work in conjunction with the 2-3way switches and the 4 way switch ?

Comment: Not much to expand on. The trick would be to find the right equipment for your specific situation. I think you would have to spend some time exploring the internet and doing the research to find what your are looking for if it is even available at a retail level.